# Applying replace multiple times (dynamicly with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

I have the current function:

```
function replaceValue(v) {
  const firstRegex = new RegExp('hello', 'g');
  const secondRegex = new RegExp('bye', 'g');

  return v.replace(firstRegex, '@').replace(secondRegex, '#');
}
```

However, now I want to add even more regex, and I want to have a datastructure that looks like this:

```
const regexStorage = [{
 value: '@',
 replace: 'hello',
}, {
 value: '#',
 replace: 'bye',
}]
```

I can't figure out a way to use that `regexStorage` to dynamically add as many replaces as they exist in the array for a given value.

I've got to this:

```
function replaceValue(v) {
  const firstRegex = new RegExp(regexStorage[0].replace, 'g');
  const secondRegex = new RegExp(regexStorage[1].replace, 'g');

  return v.replace(firstRegex, regexStorage[0].value).replace(secondRegex, regexStorage[1].value);
}
```

But that's just using the storage. I wonder how I can do this dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, you can write a one-line reduce (which was designed for this exact scenario of operating on an array but returning a single value) ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) loop as:

```js
const regexStorage = [{
 value: '@',
 replace: 'hello',
}, {
 value: '#',
 replace: 'bye',
}];

let replaceValue = v => regexStorage.reduce((v, {value, replace}) => v.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'), value), v);

let str = 'hi hello bye bi hello';
console.log(replaceValue(str));
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Would this change the original `v` value?

Comment: No. JS, like most languages including Java and C++, passes primitives by value. Updated snippet to exemplify the unchanged argument value.

Comment: I'm confused on why is the argument named `v` and also the value in the reduce function is called `v`.

Comment: You could name them different, but since they represent the same value, it makes sense to keep the same name. It's like if you had a `function purchase(cost)`, which then called `function chargeCreditCard(cost)` and `function calcTax(cost)`, all 3 functions have the same param name because it represents the same thing.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have different names: `let replaceValue = str => regexStorage.reduce((v, {value, replace}) => v.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'), value), str);
`

Comment: If you check `replaceValue(str)` it actually doesn't return the changed value, but actually your second console log, sounds the str being updated. Which makes me think that the function has modified str.

Comment: The 2nd console.log prints `str` as the original message, proving `str` is unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through your regex storage

```js
const regexStorage = [
  {
   value: '@',
   replace: 'hello',
  }, 
  {
   value: '#',
   replace: 'bye',
  }
]


function replaceValue(v) {
  for(var i = 0; i < regexStorage.length; i++){
    v = v.replace(new RegExp(regexStorage[i].replace, "g"), regexStorage[i].value);
  }
  return v;
}
var data = "hello, my name is andam. bye.";
console.log(data);
console.log(replaceValue(data));
```